# list of elements in configurationproperties and profiles

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am running an application with SpringBoot 2.1.1.RELEASE.

I have a yml file with list of elements configured in the default profile and also in a "local" profile

```
listOfSimpleObjects:
  one: oneOne, oneTwo
  three: nzerjpeojr 

listOfObjects:
  - id: idOne
    name: nameOne

---

spring:
  profiles: local

listOfSimpleObjects:
  two: twoOne,twoTwo

listOfObjects:
  - id: idTwo
    name: nameTwo
```

I want to map that configuration into a properties file  whose definition is

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyProperties {
    private Map<String, List<String>> listOfSimpleObjects = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    private List<SubConfig> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();

  public Map<String, List<String>> getListOfSimpleObjects() {
    return listOfSimpleObjects;
  }

  public void setListOfSimpleObjects(Map<String, List<String>> listOfSimpleObjects) {
    this.listOfSimpleObjects = listOfSimpleObjects;
  }

  public List<SubConfig> getListOfObjects() {
    return listOfObjects;
  }

  public void setListOfObjects(List<SubConfig> listOfObjects) {
    this.listOfObjects = listOfObjects;
  }
}

public class SubConfig {
  private String id;
  private String name;

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Running with the profile "local" I was expecting to have a **MyProperties** object with three elements in the **listOfSimpleObjects** and two in the **listOfObjects** but it is not the case.

Below a Junit test that tells me that there is only one element in the **listOfObjects**.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@SpringBootTest
public class MyPropertiesTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyProperties props;

    @Test
    public void testOnListOfStrings() {
        // this assertion is ok :)
        assertThat(props.getListOfSimpleObjects()).hasSize(3);
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnListOfObjects() {
        // this assertion fails :(
        assertThat(props.getListOfObjects()).hasSize(2);
    }
}
```

I asked a colleague of mine who that it was all about the key of the elements as the yml file is at first represented in a big **HashMap**.

So I guess there is no real answer to the question I could ask, but anyway:

- is there any way to have a merge version of the **listOfObject** ?
- Could SpringBoot be enhanced in order to support such feature (ie in case of detection of a list of items the merge is possible)

Thanks for any kind of answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *is there any way to have a merge version of the listOfObject ?*

Out of the box, no as the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-complex-type-merge) states :

> When lists are configured in more than one place, overriding works by
>   replacing the entire list.

About :

> *Could SpringBoot be enhanced in order to support such feature (ie in*
>   *case of detection of a list of items the merge is possible)*

You can open an issue/request on the [Spring Boot Git](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues).

And you guessed it works for Map as the doc states :

> For Map properties, you can bind with property values drawn from
>   multiple sources.  However, for the same property in multiple sources,
>   the one with the highest priority is used.

As simple and limited workaround (it works with only one specific profile. With two you will still have the overriding issue) you could specify a new property name for the list in the yaml of the specific profile.
So you would have two lists but it doesn't matter as finally you can merge it when the bean was completely loaded from the  `@PostConstruct` annotated method.

Sample :

```
   private List<SubConfig> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();
   private List<SubConfig> listOfObjectsFromProfile = new ArrayList<>();

   //... getters and setters 

   @PostConstruct
   public void mergeList() {
        listOfObjects.addAll(listOfObjectsFromProfile);
   }
```

Comment: damn... thanks a lot for your first link. I read so many spring document but missed this one. I'll see if I open a request or not...